# Why does this nonlinear ODE solution not work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am relatively new to Python and trying to use it to solve a second order nonlinear differential equation, specifically the Poisson-Boltzmann equation in an electrolyte.

$$\phi''(r) + \frac2 r\phi'(r) = k^2\sinh(\phi(r))$$

Essentially it describes the decay of electrostatic potential ($\phi$) away from a charged surface in an electrolyte with the rate of decay governed by a parameter $k$.

- $\phi(r)$ - the potential at $r$
- $\mathrm d\phi(r)$ - derivative of potential at $r$
- $r$ - distance from the surface (I am solving for $r = 1$ to $r = R$ in this case)

and the boundary conditions

- $\phi(1) = 5$
- $\mathrm d\phi(R) = 0$

The problem bit of code is as follows

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import root
from pylab import * # for plotting commands

k = 0.5 
phi = 5 
dphi = -10
R = 21

def deriv(z,r): # return derivatives of the array z   (where z = [phi, phi'])
    return np.array([
    (z[1]),
    ((k**2)*sinh(z[0]))-((2/r)*z[1])
    ])


result = odeint(deriv,np.array([phi,dphi]),np.linspace(1,R,1017), full_output = 1)
```

Generally for low values of k the integration works fine and I can use root from scipy.optimize to solve it subject to the boundary conditions, however when I try to use relatively large values of k (0.5 and higher) the integration runs into problems and outputs the following error

```
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
```

Having run it with full_output = 1 and had a look at the `tcur` parameter it seems to count up smoothly until a certain point and then oscillate wildly from very large to very small values. At the same point `nfe` the number of function evaluations drops to zero. When working correctly the tcur parameter runs smoothly from 1 to R. Could anyone enlighten me to why this is happening? Is it a problem with my implementation or is there an instability in the equation?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use Latex in the question, I didn't realise you could!